# Why is variable substitution called variable substitution if we retrieve the value?

Tags: variable-substitution

I've read [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html) the following text:

> The name of a variable is a placeholder for its value, the data it
>   holds. Referencing (retrieving) its value is called variable
>   substitution.

If we retrieve/or reference the value, why is the terminology is "to substitute" and not just "to retrieve" or "to reference"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it in terms of the character strings: you start with

```
${variable}
```

and after variable substitution that becomes

```
value
```

The placeholder is *replaced* by the value, hence variable substitution. There’s no reference to the variable after this (the shell doesn’t remember where the value came from).