# What is command substitution in a shell?

Tags: command-substitution

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Bash and I tried to read in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution), in [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) and in [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), but I failed to understand the meaning of "command substitution" in shell-scripting in general, and in Bash in particular, as in:

```
$(command)
```

or

```
`command`
```

What is the meaning of this term?

Edit: When I first published this question I already knew the pure concept of substitution and also the Linux concept of [variable substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403867/what-is-variable-expansion-in-bash) (replacing a variable with its value by execution), yet I still missed the purpose of this shell feature from the documentation for whatever reason or group of reasons.

---

## My answer after question locked

Command substitution is an operation with dedicated syntax to both execute a command and to have this command's **output** hold (stored) by a variable for later use.

### An example with `date`:

```
thedate="$(date)"
```

We can then print the result using the command `printf`:

```
printf 'The date is %s\n' "$thedate"
```

1. The command substitution syntax is `$()`.
2. The command itself is `date`.
3. Combining both we get `$(date)`, its value is the result of the substitution (that we could get after [execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execution_(computing))).
4. We save that value in a variable, `$thedate`, for later use.
5. We display the output value held by the variable with `printf`, per the command above.

Note: `\n` in `printf` is a line-break.

Comment: OK, everyone needs to relax and stop accusing each other of trolling. If you don't like a question, then downvote or ignore it _and walk away_. If you feel you're being attacked in comments, then do not engage but flag _and walk away_.

Comment: Also related: [What's the difference between $(stuff) and \`stuff\`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/23408)

Comment: Displaying the output of a command using command substitution and `echo` is a bad example of command substitution because 1) the output would have been displayed anyway, 2) `printf` is safer to use for variable data. The example could as well be written `date | sed 's/^/Today is /'`

Comment: @Kusalananda I see your point that printing it immediately (with `printf`) is useless. I changed the phrasing a bit, from immediately to `sometime later`, is it more appealing?

Comment: The example might be `thedate=$(date)`, followed by `printf 'The date is %s\n' "$thedate"`.

Comment: @Kusalananda you are the best Linux teacher I ever met. I now fully understand the concept (edited).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

"Command substitution" is the name of the feature of the shell language that allows you to execute a command and have the output of that command replace (substitute) the text of the command.

There is no other feature of the shell language that allows you to do that.

A command substitution, i.e. the whole `$(...)` expression, is *replaced* by its output, which is the primary use of command substitutions.

The command that the command substitution executes, is executed in a subshell, which means it has its own environment that will not affect the parent shell's environment.

Not all subshell executions are command substitutions though (see further examples at end).

Example showing that a command substitution is executed in a subshell:

```
$ s=123
$ echo "hello $( s=world; echo "$s" )"
hello world
$ echo "$s"
123
```

Here, the variable `s` is set to the string `123`. On the next line, `echo` is invoked on a string containing the result of a command substitution. The command substitution sets `s` to the string `world` and echoes this string.  The string `world` is *the output of the command in the command substitution* and thus, if this was run under `set -x`, we would see that the second line above would have been expanded to `echo 'hello world'`, which produces `hello world` on the terminal:

```
$ set -x
$ echo "hello $( s=world; echo "$s" )"
++ s=world
++ echo world
+ echo 'hello world'
hello world
```

(`bash` adds an extra level of `+` prompts to every level of a command substitution subshell in the trace output, other shells may not do this)

Lastly, we show that the command inside the command substitution was run in its own subshell, because it did not affect the value of `s` in the calling shell (the value of `s` is still `123`, not `world`).

There are other situations where commands are executed in subshells, such as in

```
echo 'hello' | read message
```

In `bash`, unless you set the `lastpipe` option (only in non-interactive instances), the `read` is executed in a subshell, which means that `$message` will not be changed in the parent shell, i.e. doing `echo "$message"` after the above command will echo an empty string (or whatever value `$message` was before).

A process substitution in `bash` also executes in a subshell:

```
cat < <( echo 'hello world' )
```

This too is distinct from a command substitution.

Comment: For bash 4.2 up, _if_ shopt lastpipe is set, job control is not active, and the pipeline is not backgrounded, the last command does _not_ run in a subshell.

Comment: You say, “There is no other feature of the shell language that allows you to do that.”  Well, at the risk of splitting hairs, you can do `cmd₁ > myfile` / ``read -r var < myfile`` / `cmd₂ "$var"`.  If necessary, you can expand that to handle multi-line data.

Comment: @G-Man Yes, and you may also write out a new shell script to a file and execute that. There is no other feature that provides a way of _substituting_ a piece of text with the output of a command though.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=$(command)
```

will store the result value of `command` into the variable.

There is really no more to it.

As a side note, I believe:

```
a=`command`
```

has been deprecated and has the same meaning as above.

Comment: _result_ here is the standard output of the command stripped of all its trailing newline characters (and some variations in between shells if the output is non-text). Note that `\`...\`` is the Bourne of csh syntax while `$(...)` is the Korn/POSIX syntax (with `\`...\`` still supported for backward compatibility)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for valuable information, and feel free to edit the answer for it to include it.