# What problem/pattern justifies using command substitution?

Tags: command-substitution

I raised a few server environments with Ubuntu and Bash, on "self managed shell" hosting providers like DigitialOcean, on which I ran Drupal/WordPress applications.

All that time I didn't have a necessity to use what's called "[command substition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440088/what-is-command-substitution-in-a-shell)".

I ask, what will be a problem, a "pattern" in which a Bash programmer would have to use this concept? Please give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use it with `find` a lot, such as:

```
tar cvf ../junk.tar `find .`
```

Also, as part of a poor-man's IDE:

```
vi `grep mysearcstring *.[ch]`
```

The above are command-line examples.  I also use it in scripts a lot, and would be hard-pressed without it.  The most common case is probably as mentioned above, to set shell variables from the output of a command:

```
NOW=`date`
```

I use back-quotes by old habit, but the `$(command)` syntax is far better since you can embed one inside another.  With back-quotes, you have to know just where to put the escape `\` characters and it's a nuisance.

Answer (score 6):

Command substitution means  to run a shell command and store its output to a variable or display back using echo command. For example, display date and time:

```
echo "Today is $(date)"
```

It is useful in situations where my command receives as parameter the output of another command or example.

Comment: That's an unfortunate example in that `date` could do the same thing with `date +'Today is %a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'` and also because `printf` is preferable over `echo` when outputting variable data.

Comment: Also, `date | sed 's/^/Today is /'`... Using a command substitution to display data using `echo` is simply not a good or even idiomatic example of the use of command substitutions.

Comment: vfbsilva you might want to change the example to use printf and not use date?

Comment: I might, problem is than I will be answering another questions. You can accept the next answer I couldn't care less the point is im not here to discuss best practices I was just showing a concept which imho was properly presented than this became code golfing and I'm not on the mood

Answer (score 4):

From [the Command Substitution subsection in the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03):

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to be substituted in place of the command name itself.

Command substitutions allow for a handy way of making use of a command's output without the need for first writing it to a temporary file and then reading it in from that file.  This is best done if the command's output is a short string on a single line.

Some people use command substitutions to collect output from a command even though the amount of output may be a multi-line document.  This is generally *not* a good way of using command substitution.  Instead, the standard Unix idiom of passing data between processing stages using pipelines or temporary files should be used.

---

Examples of command substitutions that I use:

For example, to figure out whether the current user is executing the script as root:

```
if [ "$( id -u )" -ne 0 ]; then
   echo 'This script requires root privileges, re-run with sudo' >&2
   exit 1
fi
```

The `$(id -u)` command substitution will be substituted with the output of `id -u`, which will return the UID (an integer) of the current user.

Another example.  I'm using GnuPG to sign `git` commits.  For GnuPG to work properly, I need to set `GPG_TTY` to the name of the current terminal device in my interactive shell's initialization file.  I do this with

```
export GPG_TTY="$( tty )"
```

This sets `GPG_TTY` to something like `/dev/ttyp4` depending on what the current terminal device is in the shell session.

Another example. I have a script that has to treat running on a Solaris machine as a special case:

```
case "$( uname -s )" in
    SunOS)
        # code specific for Solaris
        ;;
    *)
        # code for all other Unix platforms
esac
```

Another example.  The `getconf PATH` command returns the "default path" for the current system.  I use it under some circumstances to reset the `PATH` variable to a "sane default" value:

```
PATH="$( getconf PATH )"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another example:

- In Docker you can clean off stopped containers using:

  ```
  docker rm containerID containerID containerID ...`
  ```
- You can also get the ids of the containers that have stopped running with:

  ```
  docker ps -q -f "status=exited"
  ```
- So you can clean off all the stopped containers with:

  ```
  docker rm $(docker ps -q -f "status=exited")
  ```

... where the ids produced by `docker ps` are substituted to the `$(docker ps...)` string to be used by the `docker rm` command.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation pattern that makes this usage necessary is that Unix shells execute each non-builtin command in a child process. The child process cannot modify the context of its parent. Command substitution can cause the shell to use textual output of a non-builtin command as if it had been written in the shell script or typed on the command line.