# Create bash prompt that shows the directory after my home directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, prompt

For example, if my home directory is 'FirstLast' and I am inside of

```
/usr/FirstLast/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3
```

I want my prompt to read

```
[username@srv1 Dir1]
```

regardless of how deep in my directory I am. So the prompt should show 'Dir1' whether I am in Dir2 or Dir3.

I don't want the whole path to show by using pwd and I don't want the current directory.

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what you want? The path you show - **/usr/FirstLast/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3** - has nothing to do with your home directory. Do you want your prompt to permanently show something?

Comment: I want my prompt to always show the directory after my home directory, if I am in one of the directories inside of my home directory. In my example, I am in Dir3 but the directory immediately after my home directory is Dir1, so that's what I want shown. Even if I am in Dir2, I want the prompt to show Dir1.

Answer (score 1):

use `\W` (capital W) instead of `\w` (lowercase) in your `PS1` string.  e.g.

```
PS1='[\u@\h \W] '
```

From `man bash`:

> `\w`     the  current  working  directory,  with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde (uses the value of the `PROMPT_DIRTRIM`  variable)
>
> `\W`     the basename of the current working directory, with `$HOME` abbreviated with a tilde

In `bash`, you can also set the `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` variable:

> `PROMPT_DIRTRIM`
>
> If set to a number greater than zero, the value is used  as  the
>   number of trailing directory components to retain when expanding
>   the `\w` and `\W`  prompt string escapes (see PROMPTING  below).
>   Characters removed are replaced with an ellipsis.

---

If you want the prompt to always display the directory two levels above the current directory (or something similarly complicated or unusual), you will need to use [command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440088/what-is-command-substitution-in-a-shell) inside the PS1 string.

Note that the PS1 string has to be enclosed in single-quotes, not double-quotes - otherwise you'll get the return value of the command-subst at the time PS1 was defined, rather than it being re-evaluated every time the prompt is displayed.

e.g.

```
PS1='[\u@\h $(basename $(realpath ../../))] '
```

Comment: i just noticed you said ` I don't want the current directory.`, so the above won't do what you want (i'd delete it except that it may be useful to other people).   How do you expect to be able to define **which** particular element of the path string should be displayed in the prompt?  paths can be of arbitrary length.  Always 2 levels above the CWD?

Comment: you'd have to write a shell function (or script) to do what you want, and then call that function inside PS1 - e.g. `PS1='[\u@\h $(myfunction)] '`.   Note1: this will cause the function to be executed every time the prompt is displayed.  Note2: the PS1 string has to be enclosed in single-quotes and not double-quotes, otherwise you'll get the return value of the function at the time PS1 was defined.

Comment: Yeah, the arbitrary length of the path is the problem. I guess I was hoping that since 'cd ~'  took me to my home directory, perhaps there was a way to keep track of the following directory that I'm currently in (Dir1). I'm fine running the function every time, I'm just not sure how to create it.

Comment: You couldn't do that with a simple call to basename.  you'd have to write a function that checked if `pwd` contained $HOME.  If it does, print the next directory in pwd below $HOME.  If it doesn't (i.e. you're outside of $HOME, perhaps in /etc or /var or /usr/share/doc or somewhere), do something else (which you haven't defined in your Q - maybe print the full directory).

Comment: personally, i think this kind of thing is a waste of time, and just slows down the shell with pointless calls to functions and external programs.   a bit of bling that is briefly satisfying and then ignored 99% of the time.   It's simpler and faster just to display the full path with `\w` or the last element of it it with `\W`.

Answer (score 0):

If you in a `zsh` situation, make the variable of current path to `%-2d` in `PROMPT`. That is what you want.

What in my `.zshrc`:

```
PROMPT="[username@srv1 %-2d]"
```