# Add prefix backslash and quotes to comma separated columns in shell script

Tags: shell-script

Need to convert the below string to add prefix backslash and suffix backslash for comma separated columns. String values can be dynamic values (some times we get two comma separated values or three comma separated values ..etc)

Thanks for your help

```
var="ABC,BCD,EFG,ZYZ,XYZ,ADF"
```

```
output : \"ABC\",\"BCD\",\"EFG\",\"ZYZ\",\"XYZ\",\"ADF\"
```

Comment: Yes, three upper case letters. yes, it can be empty. yes values contain commans

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$var" | sed 's;\([A-Z]\{3\}\);\\"\1\\";g'
\"ABC\",\"BCD\",\"EFG\",\"ZYZ\",\"XYZ\",\"ADF\"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . I need to assign output value into another variable. I am getting an errror.   ``` pr= echo "$var" | sed 's;\([A-Z]\{3\}\);\\"\1\\";g'  echo$pr```

Comment: [Look up command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440123/338177): `pr=$(echo "$var" | sed 's;\([A-Z]\{3\}\);\\"\1\\";g')`.

Comment: The command you posted is missing backslashses in the parenthesis, and there must not be spaces between the ssignment: `pr=$(...`