# How do i print the path of excuatable in echo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

SO i have a Bash Script like this and goal is to determine the path of an executable file and i want to print it, here is what i'm doing

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

exepath=which exe

echo "$exepath"
```

Now this instead of printing path its starting the exe file in my system, how do i print the path stored in exepath variable.

Comment: You are looking for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

Comment: I understood. Follow [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440123/338177).

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Is outputting the pathname _all_ you want to do in your script? In that case, the variable is not needed and you could do it with just `command -v exe`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
exepath=which exe
```

(this command just runs `exe`, previously setting the environment variable `exepath` to literal value `which`)

you should use

```
exepath=`which exe`
```

or

```
exepath=$(which exe)
```

Comment: Better with `command -v exe`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249