# USB reset using lsusb output

Tags: bash, awk, pipe, lsusb

I have a USB device that I wish to reset automatically, there are two USB devices currently, but at times there may be more.

```
[user1@gs10 devt]$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1604:10c0 Tascam Dell Integrated Hub
```

Things to note:

- The device number will change periodically (firmware issues (my end))
- The ID will be dynamic as different Tascam Hubs are plugged in
- The string may also change, whitespaces, dashes.

The device I wish to reset is Device 007. My method to identify the device ID is as follows:

```
[user1@gs10 devt]$ lsusb | grep "Tascam" | awk '{printf $6 "\n"}'
1d6b:0003
```

Works OK. Now I want to run the kernerl's usbreset command as a one liner without manually typing in the vendor ID, any reccomendations?

My attempt and goal:

```
lsusb | grep "Tascam" | awk '{printf "/usr/bin/usbreset %d", $6}'
[user1@gs10 devt]$ sudo /usr/bin/usbreset 1d6b:0003
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is command substitution in a shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440088/what-is-command-substitution-in-a-shell)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Maybe more something like this, not really working though ```lsusb | grep "Tascam" | awk '{printf "/usr/bin/usbreset %d", $6}'```

Comment: Does `usbreset` take an arbitrary number of device IDs? I.e. `usbreset ID1 ID2 ID3 ...` or only *one* at a time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option could be to use `system()` directly from within `awk`:

---

## 1. Validate

Validate by requesting device from `lsusb`:

```
lsusb | awk '/Tascam.*Hub$/{ system("lsusb -d " $6) }'
```

That would take `vendor:product`, (field 6), from whole lines matching:

- `Tascam<Anything zero or more times>Hub<END-OF-LINE>`

and execute: `lsusb -d vendor:product`

*This would execute on ***all*** matching Tascam hubs*.

---

## 2. Real call

Actually call `usbreset`:

```
lsusb | sudo awk '/Tascam.*Hub$/{ system("/usr/bin/usbreset " $6) }'
```

Or perhaps better, exit if error:

```
lsusb | sudo awk '/Tascam.*Hub/{ if (system("/usr/bin/usbreset " $6)) exit 1 }'
```

As *`system(expression)`* return exit status of the command, and `0` is success, one can use `if ()` to check as if status is <> 0 it would proceed with `exit 1`. Exit with something else then `0` to signal error.

Optionally use `!= 0` if you find that easier to read. And perhaps throw in an error.

```
lsusb | sudo awk '
/Tascam.*Hub/ { 
    if (system("/usr/bin/usbreset " $6) != 0) {
        print "usbreset failed" >"/dev/stderr"
        exit 1 
    } 
}'
```

## 3. Wrapper + filter on Device

If you want to *filter* by device-number, it would likely be best to wrap it in a shell-script (which you likely would anyhow), and then do something like:

```c
#! /bin/sh -

# Check argument is given
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    printf 'Missing device number\n' >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Check sudo or abort
sudo echo >/dev/null || exit 1

lsusb |
sudo awk -v dev="$1" '
BEGIN {
    dev = sprintf("%03d:", dev)
    eno = 1
}
$4 == dev && /Tascam.*Hub/ {
    if (system("/usr/bin/usbreset " $6) != 0) {
        eno = 2
    } else {
        eno = 0
    }
    # Exit on first match of device-number + name
    exit
}
END {
    if (eno == 0)
        print "OK"
    else if (eno == 1)
        print "No device found" >"/dev/stderr"
    else if (eno == 2)
        print "usbreset failed" >"/dev/stderr"
    exit eno
}'
```

#### Note on `usbreset`

Not able to install it locally, but looks like some take argument as:

```
/dev/bus/usb/<bus>/<device-number>
```

In that case you might need to use something like:

```c
# Testing:

system(sprintf("ls -l /dev/bus/usb/%03d/%03d", $2, $4))

# Testing:

system(sprintf("/usr/bin/usbreset /dev/bus/usb/%03d/%03d", $2, $4))
```

---

## 4. Note on things in question:

1. `grep` when `awk` is next up is an unnecessary step. `awk` matches regular expressions – and it in this case it is a simple string (in your code).

`awk '/^foo/{ this line starts with foo }'` etc.

2. `printf $6 "\n"`

Looks like you want to print `$6` + line-feed. That would be either of:

```c
print $6
printf "%s\n", $6
```

It also tells awk to use `$6` as format string. This can go bad, and is in general not a good thing to do. If `$6` was for example `foo%dbar`, awk would expect a digit as arameter. etc.

3. `printf "/usr/bin/usbreset %d", $6`, say *"print digit"* and here  value is *"$6"*. As field six is `hex:hex` the *printf* statement will only print the first digits, if any, else zero.

- `12a1:06df` -> `12`
- `a112:3619` -> `0`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat file | awk '$7=="Tascam"{print $6}' | xargs echo sudo /usr/bin/usbreset
sudo /usr/bin/usbreset 1604:10c0
```

or:

```
$ echo sudo /usr/bin/usbreset "$(cat file | awk '$7=="Tascam"{print $6}')"
sudo /usr/bin/usbreset 1604:10c0
```

Replace `cat file` with `lsusb` and remove the `echo` when you're happy with the output and want to actually execute the command currently being echoed.