# How to take the number including dot from an output of one command and use it in another one?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, command-substitution

How to take the number including dot from an output of one command and use it in another one?

For example, this command

```
chia wallet show -w standard_wallet
```

gives this result

```
Wallet height: xxxxxx
Sync status: Synced
Balances, fingerprint: xxxxxxx

Chia Wallet:
   -Total Balance:         0.192267662015 xch (192267662015 mojo)
   -Pending Total Balance: 0.192267662015 xch (192267662015 mojo)
   -Spendable:             0.192267662015 xch (192267662015 mojo)
```

I want to take the number `0.192267662015` from the `Spendable` line to use in another command which will become

```
chia wallet send -a 0.192267662015
```

There will only be one `Chia Wallet` section in the output, and only one `Spendable` line.

How to write a script to do this? I have been looking up to `grep`, `sed` and `xargs` but not sure how to put them in the use correctly.

Comment: Could you please provide more context? E.g. https://www.linuxfoundation.org/press/linux-foundation-announces-an-intent-to-form-the-openwallet-foundation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have one `Wallet` section, and you want to use the `Spendable` amount, the following approach should work:

```
chia wallet send -a "$(chia wallet show -w standard_wallet | awk '$1=="-Spendable:"{print $2}')"
```

The idea is as follows:

- The `wallet send` command receives its "amount" via [command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/440088/377345) (i.e. the `$( ... )` is replaced by the output of the enclosed command).
- The enclosed command is the `wallet show` command whose output is piped to an `awk` program for text processing.
- The `awk` program will split the lines it receives from the `wallet show` command into "fields" at (contiguous) whitespace. It is designed to print the second field (`$2`) if the first field is equal to `-Spendable:`. *Note that this approach works in this simplicity only because the "Key" is a single contiguous string without "internal" whitespace in this particular case.*
- As a result, the `$( ... )` used as "value" for the `-a` option is replaced by `0.192267662015` for the above example.

Since this involves financial transactions, be sure to test the inner command (inside the `$( ... )`) before doing anything unrecoverable.

---

If you want to change the number of digits, you can use `printf` instead of `print` and use the "well-known" formatting options, e.g.:

```
awk '$1=="-Spendable:"{printf "%.4f\n",$2}'
```

If you want to force rounding down, you can truncate the string (as per a comment by Ed Morton):

```
print ((p=index($2,".")) ? substr($2,1,p+3) : $2)
```