# Syntax Question for Bash using pipes

Tags: bash, text-processing, command-substitution

I am trying to set a variable to a value returned by a program (lynx).  I cannot get past which parenthesis or bracket I use to accomplish my goal.

I have this:

```
DEBFILE=${(lynx -listonly -dump https://gridtracker.org/release.html) | grep .deb | grep nwjs | awk '{ print $2 }'}
```

Where am I going off the rails.  Be easy on me.  I haven't messed with this in a while.

I simplified the statement to include the URL.
Ultimately I would like to use a variable for the URL in that code block as well.

such as...

```
DEBFILE=${(lynx -listonly -dump ${GT_DOWNLOAD_LINK} ) | grep .deb | grep nwjs | awk '{ print $2 }'}
```

as it is defined already near the beginning of my script.

I know it is a syntax problem because I broke it down into a few more lines, echo'd the command to a file, and read it back into a variable that way.

THIS works

```
echo $(lynx -listonly -dump https://gridtracker.org/release.html | grep .deb | grep nwjs) | awk '{ print $2 }' >> temp.txt
        DEBFILE=$(cat temp.txt)
        echo $DEBFILE
```

Comment: You probably want something like `debfile=$(lynx -listonly -dump https://gridtracker.org/release.html | grep -Pom1 '\S*nwjs\S*\.deb$') || die "Can't determine nwjs URL"`

Answer (score 3):

You indeed have nested syntax errors, probabily arising from a confusion about variable expansion and command substitution.

What you want to achieve is [command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/440088/377345), i.e. you want to assign to the variable `DEBFILE` the *output* of a command. This is done as follows:

```bash
DEBFILE=$( your command )
```

The syntax `${ ... }` you used in your original attempt is instead [parameter/variable expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), where you "dereference" the shell variable whose name is placed in the curly braces. Note that `${VARIABLE}` is basically the same as `$VARIABLE`, so for the first command you showed, your shell would try to look up a variable whose *name* is `(lynx -listonly -dump https://gridtracker.org/release.html) | grep .deb | grep nwjs | awk '{ print $2 }'` and assign its value to `DEBFILE`.<sup>(1)</sup>

The correct way to achieve your goal should simply be

```bash
DEBFILE=$(lynx -listonly -dump https://gridtracker.org/release.html | grep .deb | grep nwjs | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

and you could probably replace the `grep`-`grep`-`awk` pipeline by a single `awk` command, which would probably look like

```bash
DEBFILE=$(lynx -listonly -dump https://gridtracker.org/release.html | awk '/\.grep/ && /nwjs/ { print $2 }')
```

or

```bash
DEBFILE=$(lynx -listonly -dump https://gridtracker.org/release.html | awk '(index($0,".deb") && index($0,"nwjs")) { print $2 }')
```

**Note** that the code you labelled as "This works" basically does exactly what I proposed, just with an unnecessary `echo` and the intermediate step of writing the output to a file from which it is read back to the variable `$DEBFILE`:

- `echo $(lynx ... | grep .deb | grep nwjs)` has the same effect as `lynx ... | grep .deb | grep nwjs` (but could possibly introduce unwanted reformatting of whitespace) because it basically makes the console output of the `lynx ... | grep ... | grep ...` pipeline an argument to `echo`, which will simply print it to the console (again).
- So, `echo $(lynx ... | grep .deb | grep nwjs) | awk '{ print $2 }'` does the same as `lynx ... | grep .deb | grep nwjs | awk '{ print $2 }'`

---

<sup>(1)</sup> As noted by Stéphane Chazelas, `ksh93` actually does support command substitution in a `${ cmd; }` form, but it requires the command to end in a `;`, it is not POSIX-compatible, and Bash doesn't support it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will test it out and see where I went wrong. I could have sworn I tried it like you posted. I cat'd it out to a file and got it to work, which is strange.

Comment: @JoeBurden I would be interested to know how your test turned out. Also, if you found the answer useful, you may consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I have been temporarily torn away from this project unexpectedly.  Ultimately, this is what I went with for now.       ``` echo $(lynx -listonly -dump $GT_DOWNLOAD_LINK | grep .deb | grep nwjs) | awk '{ print $2 }' > NWJS_LINK.txt ```

Comment: When I revisit the issue I will make sure everyone gets appropriate credit and acceptance.  I did have a problem with ending a loop that exacerbated my problem.